# How do I sort table by multiple columns in TablePlus

Tags: macos

> Build 204 - New features and bug fixes Release date: 18 Mar 2019.
>
> - Supported sort table by
>   multiple columns. Supported duplicate multiple rows

I haven't been able to figure out how to use this feature

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developers?

Answer (score 0):

Per this answer, https://github.com/TablePlus/TablePlus/issues/358#issuecomment-553415908, Hold Command + Right-click on the column to multiple columns sort